# impact of js script a the end of the html page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a html web page, i load in my main section the content of another html page. I have a js script section at the botton of my charged page. I use jquery.

```
<div id="main">
</div>
```

Other page

```
<div>
...
    <div id="roomCheckoutResult" class="hide">
    ...
    </div>
</div>

<script>

  $('#dateRoomCheckout').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  });

  $("roomCheckoutResult").show();

</script>
```

Line with function show don't work. If i use directly

```
document.getElementById("roomCheckoutResult").className="";
```

that work.

So why my line with show don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
$("roomCheckoutResult").show();
```

to this:

```
$("#roomCheckoutResult").show();
```

You target an id value by using a `#` at the start of the selector.

And, it goes without saying that you have to make sure that jQuery is loaded before using it.

Comment: # was the problem. show did not work, but that was fine with removeClass("hide");